# Return to previous commands in bash script [PART 2 FOLLOWUP]

Tags: bash

I previously asked a similar question here: [Return to previous commands in bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051090/return-to-previous-commands-in-bash-script)

The difference I have now is, the answer I received only partially works. I tried to contact the answerer, but I got no response.

Anyway, I am trying to add more menus and have more "prev" options. For example, I'd like to have:

```
while [[ $answer -ne '3' ]];do
echo "Choose option:"
echo "1 - Begin"
echo "2 - Load"
echo "3 - Exit"
read -p "Enter Answer [1-2-3]:" answer
    case "$answer" in
    1) while [[ "$nm" == '' ]];do read -p "What is your Name:" nm;done # Keep asking for a name if the name is empty == ''
    if [[ $nm == "prev" ]];then nm=""; else echo "Hello $nm" && break; fi  # break command breaks the while wrapper loop 

##Begin my custom code:

    read -p ""What is your favourite colour?" cr
    if [[ $cr == "prev" ]];then cr="" # And return to "What is your name"
    echo "$cr is my favourite, too!
# And keep going on and on, utilizing the "prev" command to go back to the previous question.

#End my custom code.

     ;;
    2) echo 'Load' ;;
    3) echo 'exiting...' ;;                                          # Number 3 causes while to quit.
    *) echo "invalid selection - try again";;                        # Selection out of 1-2-3 , menu reloaded
esac                                                                 # case closing 
done                                                                 # while closing
echo "Bye Bye!"
```

Please understand that I am having a difficult time writing this. Please go easy on me ^^;

Comment: Why don't you divide your menus into separate functions and call the function for previous menu on some `back` or `previous menu` option? Is this what you are asking to go back and forth in multiple menu interfaces, right?

Comment: I think so. (sorry my English is not that good). An example would be, `What is your favourite colour?` - _prev_ `What is your name?` - _prev_ `Choose option`

Comment: No problem. You can divide each menu in separate functions like `mainMenu()`, `colorsMenu()`, `infoMenu()`, etc. And, then you can move the relevant functioning into a menu. On `prev`, it'll be easy for you to just call a function and it'll show the relevant options. Did you get it?

Comment: I believe so, thanks for explaining! ^_^

Comment: That's great! Always welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this,
I included some explanatory comments.

```
begin() {
    # local variables that should not be visible outside this function
    local name color

    while :; do
        while [[ $name == '' ]]; do
            read -p "What is your Name:" name
        done

        if [[ $name == prev ]]; then
            # exit function, return to menu
            return
        fi
        echo "Hello $name"

        read -p "What is your favourite colour?" color
        if [[ $color == prev ]]; then
            # clear the current variable, and the previous too, to repeat previous question
            color=
            name=
            continue
        fi
        echo "$color is my favourite, too!"

        # all done here, return to menu
        return
    done
}

while [[ $answer -ne 3 ]]; do
    echo "Choose option:"
    echo "1 - Begin"
    echo "2 - Load"
    echo "3 - Exit"
    read -p "Enter Answer [1-2-3]:" answer
    case "$answer" in
        1) begin ;;
        2) echo 'Load' ;;
        3) echo 'exiting...' ;;
        *) echo "invalid selection - try again" ;;
    esac
done
echo "Bye Bye!"
```

Comment: Wonderful !! Thank you! I would upvote all of you for your helpfulness, but alas, since I'm new I am unable to vote :(

Comment: Quick question, what do I do if I have a third option? Or more than that? For example, `What is your dog's name?` that also uses `prev` to go backwards.

Comment: @leetbacoon do like `color` above, but instead of clearing `color` and `name`, clear `dogname` and `color`. That is, the general rule for any further options is to clear the current variable and the previous one.